# Drop Database Error For Azure Synapse Database

Tags: azure-synapse

When I try to drop a database in my builtin synapse pool, I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot drop database "database name" because it is currently in use.
```

I've tried in both SSMS and Studio Synapse Studio and both returned errors.

I made sure there's no external datasources and file formats in the database.

The SSMS command I used was:

```
DROP DATABASE [database name]
```

Set Single_use mode doesn't work either. If you try this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database Name] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

You'll get this:

```
SINGLE_USER is not supported for ALTER DATABASE.
```

What blocks a database from being dropped in synapse?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever got a solution?. I'm having the same issue with same errors.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me is:

1. Run this in master

```sql
    select DB_NAME(database_id), 'kill '+cast(session_id as varchar(10)), *
    from sys.dm_exec_sessions
    where DB_NAME(database_id) NOT IN ('master')
    order by 1
```

2. Kill all sessions (active as well as sleeping) for the database you want to delete using the kill command returned by the query above. Run it in master:

```sql
    kill 82
```

3. Drop the database from Synapse Studio, not from SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Were you connected to MASTER?

Assuming there were no users connected, that is the only reason I can think it would be blocked.

Comment: Yes I was in the master database.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure to kill all the sessions manually.**

One of the reasons why you could get this error is that there is an active connection via SSMS/ADS/Synapse Studio/Power BI or some other tool which is using that database at the moment.

When you close all the sessions, you should be able to delete the database successfully.

### Here is the procedure for SQL serverless pool (aka SQL on-demand).

**Step 1:** Find the session which you want to kill using query bellow.

```
    SELECT 
     'Running' as [Status],
     Transaction_id as [Request ID],
     'SQL serverless' as [SQL Resource],
     s.login_name as [Submitter],
     s.Session_Id as [Session ID],
     req.start_time as [Submit time],
     req.command as [Request Type],
     SUBSTRING(
         sqltext.text, 
         (req.statement_start_offset/2)+1,   
         (
             (
                 CASE req.statement_end_offset  
                     WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(sqltext.text)  
                     ELSE req.statement_end_offset  
                 END - req.statement_start_offset
             )/2
         ) + 1
     ) as [Query Text],
     req.total_elapsed_time as [Duration]
 FROM 
     sys.dm_exec_requests req
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) sqltext
     JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON req.session_id = s.session_id
```

**Step 2:** Use the value in the Session ID column to kill the process which you want to. For example, if the Session ID is 81 then execute the following command

```
 kill 81
```

---

### Here is the procedure for SQL dedicated pool (aka SQL DW).

**Step 1:** Find the session which you want to kill using the bellow query

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions
 where [status] = 'Active' and not sql_spid = @@SPID
 GO
```

**Step 2:** Use the value in the [session_id] column to kill the process which you want to. for example if the session_id is 'SID210' then execute the following command

```
 kill 'SID210'
 GO
```

Comment: I used the query and only saw connections to the master DB where I was running the query you posted.

I tried to drop the database and still got the same error.

Comment: Can you try to delete the database from the Synapse Studio/Data activity hub?

Do you have any running requests when you go to Synapse Studio/Monitoring/SQL requests? Are all in state completed?

Comment: I tried both Synapse Studio and Data Activity Hub. Both returned errors.
The databases were new hence no activity on them.

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest creating a support request in Azure Portal where support engineers will provide solution for you since this should be investigated.

Comment: For myself on Serverless I didn't have anything actively running anything against the DB but it still refused to drop. I used `SELECT * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where database_id = DB_ID('MyDatabase')` and killed the sleeping user sessions from that list and was able to drop.